# Python: Scatter Plot with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I´m trying to do a scatter plot in python with matplotlib.

I have the following scenario:
There is a list of participants and each participant has costs in three different markets: market1, market2 and market3

On the x - axis I have the name of different participants like: name1, name2, etc.

On the y-axis I distinguish between three different costs: There are costs in the market1, market2 and market3.

How can I create a scatter plot for that ? I know that this isn´t a platform for solutions but I even don´t know to to beginn with it!

I tried the following:

```
sumName1Market1 = dfMarket1["name1"].sum()
sumName2Market1 = dfMarket1["name2"].sum()

sumName1Market2 = dfMarket2["name1"].sum()
sumName2Market2= dfMarket2["name2"].sum()

sumName1Market3 = dfMarket3["name1"].sum()
sumName2Market3 = dfMarket3["name2"].sum()

name1Costs= (sumSpotThree, sumSpotFive, sumSpotSeven)
name2Costs= (sumCAThree, sumCAFive, sumCASeven)

plt.scatter(x=["name1", "name2"], y=[name1Costs, name2Costs])
```

But it says that x and y must be the same size but I my numbers of participants and the number of the markets are not the same size. Maybe I should use a subplot?

Comment: Do you want to have 3 different y-axis? Like for each element on x, 3 different scatters on the y axis, e.g. with 3 different colors/shapes?

Comment: Yes thats exactly what I want

Comment: Could you give some example data so that we can run the code on our systems?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a second or third parasite axes, this example might help you:
[Matplotlib parasite axes](https://matplotlib.org/examples/axes_grid/demo_parasite_axes2.html)